# how to use cidoc-crm in jena

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, jena, ontology

Recently, I'm trying to approach semantic web using Jena to create RDF and make query. Now, I have successfully made a owl based RDF file in Jena. However, when I trying to use different ontologies (such as: cidoc-crm), I do not know how to import those ontologies to Jena. Does anyone know how to import them to Jena? Do I need to create a new ontology model?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the cidoc-crm ontology?   I see that there is an RDFS encoding available from [the releases section](http://www.cidoc-crm.org/official_release_cidoc.html), but only drafts of OWL DL ontologies.  The way that you would handle these two cases is different.  If you're working in pure RDF(S), you only need to _use_ the vocabulary defined in the RDFS vocabulary.  If you're working with OWL, then your ontology needs to _import_ the other ontology.

Comment: thanks for the reply, now I have a bit of confused, I would like to use cidoc-crm in jena making a RDF file to describe a collection in museums and art gallery. Is cidoc-CRM a " domain ontology" like Dublin Core or just vocabularies?

Comment: @Richard you seem to have your terminology a bit mixed up. CIDOC-CRM is a domain ontology, yes - it's an ontology for the Cultural Heritage domain. Dublin Core is _not_ a domain ontology: instead, it's a cross-domain vocabulary (cross-domain meaning that it is applicable to many different types of domain, not just "Cultural Heritage" or "Medical", or...).

Comment: Also, the difference between a vocabulary and an ontology is not an absolute one, but rather a sliding scale: any ontology is a vocabulary, but only vocabularies that are sufficiently expressive and structured are usually called ontologies. Dublin Core, which is not very structured (the basis is simply a list of useful properties, but no class structure/hierarchy of any sort) is not typically considered a proper ontology - although it's at least partly personal taste as well.

Answer (score 3):

Jena's [OntModel](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html) interface provides a convenient way of working with ontologies (including RDFS ontologies).  The following code shows how you can get an OntModel that contains the data of the ontology.  In this code, I then create another OntModel with inference support that includes the CIDOC model that I created.  With the inferencing model, it is easy to create individuals and see computed types for them, or see subclass relationships derived by the inference model.

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.Individual;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;

public class CIDOCExample {

    final static String CIDOCNS = "http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/";

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        // Load the CIDOC-CRM into an OntModel.  We won't add any reasoning capability to this model, but
        // we'll use it as a submodel of OntModels that do.  Jena can pull the document from the web, but
        // you could also download a local copy and read that.  It would certainly a bit quicker than 
        // downloading it every time.
        final OntModel cidocModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM );
        cidocModel.read( "http://www.cidoc-crm.org/rdfs/cidoc_crm_v5.1-draft-2013May.rdfs" );

        // Create an OntModel that imports the cidocModel, and give it inference support.
        final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM_RDFS_INF );
        model.addSubModel( cidocModel );

        // Retrieve a class from the OntModel and shows its subclasses.
        final OntClass e5_event = model.getOntClass( CIDOCNS+"E5_Event" );
        System.out.println( "Subclasses of E5_Event:" );
        for ( final ExtendedIterator<OntClass> it = e5_event.listSubClasses(); it.hasNext() ;) {
            System.out.println( "\t* "+it.next() );
        }

        // Create your own instance data in an OntModel that imports the cidocModel
        final Individual someJoining = model.createIndividual( "http://example.org/someJoining", cidocModel.getOntClass( CIDOCNS+"E85_Joining"));
        System.out.println( "Types of "+someJoining );
        for ( final ExtendedIterator<Resource> types = someJoining.listRDFTypes(false); types.hasNext(); ) {
            System.out.println( "\t* "+types.next() );
        }
    }
}
```

Having to obtain the classes using `OntModel.getOntClass(CIDCOCNS+"...")` is a bit clumsy, and it's very easy to make a typo.  Jena provides an excellent [schemagen](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/schemagen.html) tool that takes an ontology and generates a class of constants that represent the classes, properties, and individuals declared in the ontology.  For instance, you could use `schemagen` to create a `CIDOC` class with, e.g., a constant `OntClass` object for `E5_Event` so that instead of

```java
final OntClass e5_event = model.getOntClass( CIDOCNS+"E5_Event" );
System.out.println( "Subclasses of E5_Event:" );
for ( final ExtendedIterator<OntClass> it = e5_event.listSubClasses(); it.hasNext() ;) {
  System.out.println( "\t* "+it.next() );
}
```

you could do

```java
System.out.println( "Subclasses of E5_Event:" );
for ( final ExtendedIterator<OntClass> it = CIDOC.E5_Event.inModel( model ).listSubClasses(); it.hasNext() ;) {
  System.out.println( "\t* "+it.next() );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me so much!