# How to generate a RDF file with CIDOC CRM format

Tags: java, ios, jena, semantic-web, ontology

I am new to the semantic web development, currently I am developing a museum application and I have to create a rdf file of my tables to search a record, few parameters would be passed from IOS application which will find a record from rdf file and will give an output in json format. I found that for the museum there is a special ontology/format called a CIDOC-CRM.

My question is, how to generate a RDF file with CIDOC CRM format?

Comment: Does [how to use cidoc-crm in jena](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17546968/1281433) help?

Comment: It did help me a bit, as per my assumption that code reads a rdf file but i dont know how to create a rdf file using CIDOC-CRM ontology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reference documentation](http://www.cidoc-crm.org/comprehensive_intro.html) for CIDOC CRM indicates that there is an existing RDF and/or OWL representation of the data model. The [official releases](http://www.cidoc-crm.org/official_release_cidoc.html) page contain links for downloading the RDF representation of the data model. As of this time [version 5.1](http://www.cidoc-crm.org/rdfs/cidoc_crm_v5.1-draft-2014March.rdfs) is the newest available for download.

**Creating a Graph from Nothing**

Because you have an existing data model and vocabulary, the question of "how to generate a RDF file with the CIDOC CRM format" is equivalent to "how to generate a RDF file using the data model and vocabulary provided by CIDOC". This is a pretty common problem and it's actually quite easy.

1. Create an apache jena model.
2. write statements into it that correspond to the way graphs are laid out in CIDOC

Step two requires:

1. read the documentation to understand the graph that you will create
2. look at the RDF representation of the vocabulary to understand the terms you will use

**Creating a Graph from a Database**

If you already have a (relational) database containing this information, then it may be a rather simple translation from table names to vocabulary terms. This would involve executing a select query (using JDBC for example) and then writing statements into your jena `Model` based on the result.

**Expressing the graph as JSON**

RDF has a json serialization format JSON-LD which you can use to [write your output](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-output.html), if necessary.

Comment: **Step 2, put your statements in the box**, is made easier with a schemagen vocabulary for CIDOC CRM, as mentioned in [how to use cidoc-crm in jena](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17546968/1281433).

Comment: Alright! thanks a lot for your valuable answers, i will get back to you soon.

Comment: I have read the documentation and fortuantely i understood few terms, as per my assumption i would have to use 3 entity which are E1_CRM_Entity, E49_Time_Appeliation, E55_Type. Now, using this entity i have tried to create a RDF File, please have a look and do let me know whether it is a correct one or will have to change a bit.

Comment: <rdf:RDF xml:lang="en" xml:base="http://www.cidoc-crm.org/cidoc-crm/">
-<rdfs:Class rdf:about="E1_CRM_Entity">
<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Moderns
<crm:P1.Is_Identified_By>Peter </crm:P1.Is_Identified_By>
</rdfs:label>
</rdfs:Class rdf:about="E1_CRM_Entity">
-<rdfs:Class rdf:about="E49_Time_Appellation">
<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Moderns</rdfs:label>
<crm:P1.Is_Identified_By>1970</crm:P1.Is_Identified_By>
</rdfs:Class rdf:about="E49_Time_Appellation">

Comment: -<rdfs:Class rdf:about="E55_Type">
<rdfs:label xml:lang="en">Moderns</rdfs:label>
<crm:P1.Is_Identified_By>canvas</crm:P1.Is_Identified_By>
</rdfs:Class rdf:about="E55_Type">

Answer (score 0):

i have made a correction and i am able to serialized a file in JSON-LD format. Here is a code for that

```
xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
xmlns:crm="http://www.cidoc-crm.org/rdfs/cidoc_crm_v5.0.4_official_release.rdfs#"
xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
```

```
<crm:P102_has_title>Nativity</crm:P102_has_title>

<crm:P91_has_unit>25.6 h x 19.6 w cm</crm:P91_has_unit>

<crm:P7_took_place_at>4f</crm:P7_took_place_at>

<crm:P33_used_specific_technique>Printed Image</crm:P33_used_specific_technique>

<crm:P33_used_specific_technique>Pencil</crm:P33_used_specific_technique>

<crm:P41i_was_classified_by>Moderns</crm:P41i_was_classified_by>


<crm:P2_has_type>Painting</crm:P2_has_type>

<crm:P4_has_time-span>1933</crm:P4_has_time-span>

<crm:P52_has_current_owner>Rex WOOD</crm:P52_has_current_owner>
```

Now my question is how could i fetch only one record as i will pass a parameter from IOS app which could be P52_has_current_owner or P2_has_type or P4_has_time-span

my code to read a rdf is like this.

FileManager.get().addLocatorClassLoader(test.class.getClassLoader());

```
      Model model=FileManager.get().loadModel("H:/EclipseWorkplace/MuseumDatabaseRecommendation/src/data3.rdf");

      model.write(System.out,"JSON-LD");
```

Comment: New questions should be posted as new questions so they are not overlooked (on the outside, this post appears to be a second answer to an existing question). Additionally, if your original question was answered to your satisfaction, you should consider [marking it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).